# Update/Time stamp into cell when value change

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA code to change or to update the time stamp for 2 cells at the same row in Excel, but some how I can only have the first column to update the time stamp when I change the value but nothing happen to the second column, it return blank value.
I also want to have the sheet protected so when the time stamp is update, it is locked and not be edit but dont know how to put it into protection

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim xRg As Range
On Error Resume Next


Dim I As Range, J As Range, L As Range, M As Range
Set I = Range("I:I")
Set L = Range("L:L")

Set T = Target

' Timestamp for Trackin
If Intersect(I, T) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(I, T).Value = "Yes" Then Range("J" & T.Row).Value = Now

' Timestamp for Completion
If Intersect(L, T) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Intersect(L, T).Value = "Complete" Then Range("M" & T.Row).Value = Now

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: First, remove `On Error Resume Next`. Then, you can't use `Exit Sub` here, use `If Not Intersect(I, T) Is Nothing Then`...`End If`, and similarly for `L`.

Comment: I tried as you suggest but it still did not update the 2nd column: ' Timestamp for Trackin
    If Not Intersect(I, T) Is Nothing Then
End
If Intersect(I, T).Value = "Yes" Then Range("J" & T.Row).Value = Now


' Timestamp for Completion
If Not Intersect(L, T) Is Nothing Then
End
If Intersect(L, T).Value = "Complete" Then Range("M" & T.Row).Value = Now

Comment: Does your target range have cells in both columns? I'd think with a change event unless you are copy and pasting it will only be a single cell.

Comment: Yes, for example if I change value in I1 than J1 will have time stamp, and then if I change value in L1 then M1 will have another time stamp

Comment: Well as BigBen said you'll never get to L because you're exiting sub. I can't really read that code in the comment but it doesn't look like proper ```if``` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Add Time Stamp When Cell Changes

- Adjust the values in the constants section (the password (`PW`)).

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const cCheckList As String = "I,L"
    Const cWriteList As String = "J,M"
    Const CriteriaList As String = "Yes,Complete"
    Const PW As String = ""
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2
    
    Dim cCheck() As String: cCheck = Split(cCheckList, ",")
    Dim cWrite() As String: cWrite = Split(cWriteList, ",")
    Dim Criteria() As String: Criteria = Split(CriteriaList, ",")
    
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim ColOffset As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(cCheck)
        Set rng = Intersect(Columns(cCheck(n)) _
            .Resize(Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1).Offset(FirstRow - 1), Target)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            ColOffset = Columns(cWrite(n)).Column - Columns(cCheck(n)).Column
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Me.Unprotect Password:=PW
            updateLock rng, Criteria(n), ColOffset, Now
            Me.Protect Password:=PW
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End If
    Next n

End Sub

Sub updateLock( _
        rng As Range, _
        ByVal s As String, _
        ByVal ColOffset As Long, _
        ByVal TimeStamp As Date)
    
    Const ProcName As String = "updateLock"
    On Error GoTo clearError

    Dim aRng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each aRng In rng.Areas
        For Each cel In aRng.Cells
            If Not IsError(cel) Then
                With cel
                    If StrComp(.Value, s, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        If Not StrComp(.Value, s, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                            .Value = s
                        End If
                        .Locked = True
                        With .Offset(, ColOffset)
                            .Value = TimeStamp
                            '.Locked = True
                        End With
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        Next cel
    Next aRng

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub

clearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "        " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit

End Sub

Sub doEnableEvents()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I As Range, L As Range, T As Range
    Dim rw As Long, v As String
    
    Set I = Range("I:I")
    Set L = Range("L:L")
    Set T = Target
    rw = T.Row
    v = T.Value
    
    If Not Intersect(T, I) Is Nothing Then
        If v = "Yes" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range("J" & rw) = Now
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(T, L) Is Nothing Then
        If v = "Complete" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range("M" & rw) = Now
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version of the code will not over-write a timestanp after it has been entered.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I As Range, L As Range, M As Range
    Dim rw As Long, v As String
    
    Set I = Range("I:I")
    Set L = Range("L:L")
    Set T = Target
    rw = T.Row
    v = T.Value
    
    If Not Intersect(T, I) Is Nothing Then
        If v = "Yes" And Range("J" & rw) = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range("J" & rw) = Now
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
    
    If Not Intersect(T, L) Is Nothing Then
        If v = "Complete" And Range("M" & rw) = "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                Range("M" & rw) = Now
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The code won't change a timestamp, but you still can.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: How can I locked the cell up after the timestamp is updated ?

Comment: @Yogurt  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thank you. I mean was to protect the sheet or the cell with password protected. I tried multiple way but does not seem to work. But thank you very much. This is a good start for me